# Where do I find the exercise price and date for warrants?

Tags: stock-exchanges, warrants

Some stock exchanges offer 'warrants'. For example, on TSE, you can find swy.wt.a. My understanding is that this security gives you the right to purchase the regular stock at a specific price, until a specific date.

But, where can I find the price and date, in general ? For the example above, I can google and find it at

http://www.northernminer.com/news/tsx-and-tsxv-warrants/1003696877/
Stornoway Diamond (SWY.WT.A) - Wt buys sh @ $0.90 to Jul 3/16.

Which is great. However, how can I verify that those are the actual terms ? I won't trust a random page on the Internet.

Also, I understand that warrants can come with various non-standard terms. Where and how do I find those terms ? Or, do I simply stay away from warrants stock if I'm not fully aware of all the details of the issuing company ?

Comment: Warrants are not stocks they are a derivative of the stock similar to Options.

Comment: @Victor, edited to use a better terminology

Comment: warrants are (generally) issued either by the company itself or by banks - the terms should be on the issuing company's or bank's website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that a random page on the internet is not always a good source, but at the same time I will use Google or Yahoo Finance to look up US/EU equities, even though those sites are not authoritative and offer zero guarantees as to the accuracy of their data.

In the same vein you could try a website devoted to warrants in your market.  For example, I Googled `toronto stock exchange warrants` and the very first link took me to a site with all the information you mentioned.  The authoritative source for the information would be the listing exchange, but I've spent five minutes on the TSX website and couldn't find even a fraction of the information about that warrant that I found on the non-authoritative site.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what I'm doing, but it seems to me that for US based stocks that are registered with the SEC, you can find this information on the companies S-1 filings via an EDGAR search here: https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html

You probably should like at any S-1 amendments too, but again this is just me speculating.

If a company's stock price stays above the strike price or above a certain price, the company can change the warrant's exercise date to be sooner than it previously was. If this happens and you don't exercise the warrant in time, the warrant will expire worthless.

I'm not sure how exactly you are supposed to stay informed on any exercise date changes, though.

Comment: Companies cannot arbitrarily change the exercise date.  There can be conditional language regarding the price level for X days but this is all spelled out in the filing.

Comment: The S-1 filing is the only place I could find this info (and it's a bit buried on sec.gov). Try searching for "Placement Warrant" or "Public Warrant" in the S-1. It's a shame this fundamental info is currently so difficult to find.